# single.php crashed in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying around with yoast breadcrumbs, and where it told me to take care, I messed up. I implemented the function on a wrong way and now the website does not show anymore.
The following error appears Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in D:\Hosting\12006171\html\wp-content\themes\html5blank-master\single.php on line 149

I have had this before within my functions.php. there i could fix the problem by logging in with my ftp program and renew the file. I have tried all that with the single.php file but nothing works. Is there any way to fix this problem??? the faulthy codes are all removed but it does not want to work again..

please help

Comment: Did you backup your database before you made these changes? If not, there isn't a way to revert a database back in time by plugins. You could try to manually reset the options table of your database with a clean table and try to delete all Yoast related tables.

Comment: This is nothing but a *syntactical* error. Can you post your `single.php` ?